# What exactly is PKGBUILD and should I edit it when installing packages?

Tags: arch-linux, compiling, package-management, pacman

Whenever I use `yaourt -Syua` in my Manjaro Linux system, it'll give me

```
Edit PKGBUILD ? [Y/n] ("A" to abort)
```

and sometimes

```
Edit chromium-pepper-flash.install ? [Y/n] ("A" to abort)
```

Somewhere I read to just say no to editing these files.

The wiki : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PKGBUILD

Says the `PKGBUILD` is just some switches to alter when installing, so is it alright to just leave it default?

I haven't found information about the `.install` files, what are they?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why don't you thoroughly read the wiki page that you [linked](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PKGBUILD):

> Packages in Arch Linux are built using the **makepkg** utility and
>   information stored in PKGBUILDs. When **makepkg** is run, *it
>   **searches for a PKGBUILD** in the current directory and **follows the instructions therein** to either compile or otherwise acquire the
>   files to build a package file*

Therefore, `PKGBUILD` is a *"recipe"* for creating a package (similar to a `RPM` `spec`, `gentoo` `ebuild` etc). Sometimes, when a package is installed/removed/upgraded, it may require some scripts/programs to be automatically executed before/after the package files are written to/removed from disk so an additional *"recipe"* is needed, i.e. `.install`  (excerpt from the same link):

> install
>
> The name of the **.install** script to be included in the package. pacman
>   has the ability to store and execute a package-specific script when it
>   installs, removes or upgrades a package. **The script contains the
>   following functions which run at different times**:
>
> ```
> pre_install - The script is run right before files are extracted. One argument is passed: new package version.
> post_install - The script is run right after files are extracted. One argument is passed: new package version.
> pre_upgrade - The script is run right before files are extracted. Two arguments are passed in the following order: new package version, old package version.
> post_upgrade - The script is run after files are extracted. Two arguments are passed in the following order: new package version, old package version.
> pre_remove - The script is run right before files are removed. One argument is passed: old package version.
> post_remove - The script is run right after files are removed. One argument is passed: old package version.
> ```

Usually, you edit `PKGBUILD` to customize the way the package is built (e.g. add/remove `--configure` options, change install prefix, patch the source code, exclude files from the package  etc). Likewise, you edit `.install` to add or remove commands that should be automatically executed before/after a package install/upgrade/removal.
I'd say it's good practice to open those files when prompted and read their content just to make sure everything is OK.

Answer (score 2):

If you want install a package that is available only from [AUR](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR), [yaourt](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Yaourt) will download the desired package's `PKGBUILD` (and maybe some other files) and with PKGBUILD (the [makepkg](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Makepkg) program) will build the package so you can install it.

If you'll need you can edit the PKGBUILD but I think in the most cases it's unnecessary. If you don't want this question (and always answer YES), you can do: place into `/etc/yaourtrc` the next line:

```
EDITFILES=0
```

I'm using some packages from AUR and I never needed to edit PKGBUILD.

**Edit**: this prevents only the question about editing `PKGBUILD`. You have chance of interrupt of installing unsupported packages from AUR and you can check `PKGBUILD` before building and installing of package.

Comment: You may not need to edit it, but you should *read* every PKGBUILD before installing anything from the AUR...

Comment: You are recommending that people install unsupported software without bothering to see what it is going to do. That is, IMO, irresponsible.

Comment: No, I didn't recommend this. I recommend that doesn't need edit PKGBUILD (most cases). With default `yaourtrc` and with my recommendation yaourt will ask if you want really build the package and really want to install, so you can choice answer "no" and check PKGBUILD.

Comment: Then edit your answer to remove the recommendation to blindly install from the AUR...

Comment: @jasonwryan You may not need to edit source code, either, and while it'd be great to _read every_ line before installing anything, there is a point to where you end up having to trust trust. If you're not scrutinizing the source, then there's not really much more to lose by blindly accepting PKGBUILD.

Comment: @SpellingD I couldn't disagree more: most open source projects have many sets of eyes on them; PKGBUILDs, on the other hand, do not. Anyone "blindly accepting" an anonymous and janky shell script with root access is a fool.